Moment Generating Function and Taylor expansion with little $o$ notation
Assume a random variable $X$ has a moment generating function $M_{X}(\lambda) = \mathbb{E}\exp(e^{\lambda X})$. Is it correct to write
$$
M_X(\lambda) = \mathbb{E}\exp(e^{\lambda X}) = 1 + \lambda \mathbb{E}[X] + \frac{\lambda^2}{2}\mathbb{E}[X^2] + o(\lambda^2)
$$
from its Taylor expansion?

Yes, it is. What makes you doubt ? Taylor expansion of the exponential + linearity of expectation.
